# Выяснить является ли текст идентификатором + чтение и запись в файл

Tags: java, netbeans

Нужно было составить прогу, которая определяет является ли тест идентификатором переменной. При этом она должна поддерживать кодировку в Юникоде (идентификаторы могут содержать кириллицу). В первом коде прога работает исправно, во второй же нужно реализовать считывание и запись данных в файл. Тут то и проблема, строку "шелшелпрошелғҲҮ124feast1111" в первом коде разрешает использовать как идентификатор, а во второй нет. Проблема, я думаю, в том что при считывании он переводит в другую кодировку, хотя указана UTF-8. Как исправить я не знаю, прошу вашей помощи, заранее спасибо.

Первый код

```
package la6;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class La6 {
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
Scanner in  = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter ID's name: ");
String str  = in.nextLine();

if (isValidIdentifier(str)) {
  System.out.println("«" + str + "» - допустимое значение");  
} else
{
  System.out.println("«" + str + "» - недопустимое значение");
}
System.out.println("У™іТЈТ“ТЇТ±Т›У©Т»");
System.out.println();    
}    

public static boolean isValidIdentifier(String str) {       
if (!str.matches("[$_\u0401-\u04F9\u0041-\uFB06]+[$_0-9\u0401-\u04F9\u0041-\uFB06]+")) {
return false;
} 

String[] keyWords = {"boolean","volatile","else","instanceof","switch","true","goto","abstract","enum","int","static","false","break","assert","extends","interface","strictfp","null","continue","byte","final","long","super","do","case","finally","native","synchronized","double","catch","float","new","throw","protected","char","for","package","throws","this","class","if","private","transient","short","const","implements","public","try","while","default","import","return","void", "/", "","""};
      if (Arrays.asList(keyWords).contains(str))
{               
    return false;
}

return true;
}
}
```

Второй код:

```
package tk.lab7;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class TKLab7 {    
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in, "UTF-8"));

     System.out.print("Введите имя файла для чтения: ");
     String name = in.readLine();   

     /// Выбор кодировки чтения файла

    //System.out.println("\nУкажите кодировку: \n1: ANSI\n2: Юникод\nлюбая другая клавиша: UTF-8");
    String /*code = in.readLine(); 
    if ("1".equals(code)) */code = "UTF-8";
    /*else if ("2".equals(code)) code = "UTF-16";
    else code = "UTF-8";*/


     //считывание из файла
     BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(name + ".txt"), code));
      String original_text = "";
        int c;
        while((c=reader.read())!=-1){                  
            original_text += ((char)c);
        } 

        //вывод текста из файла в консоль
        System.out.println("\nПроверяемая строка: ");    
        System.out.print(original_text);

        System.out.print("\nВведите имя файла для записи: ");
        String name2 = in.readLine();

        // запись измененного теста  в файл 
         OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(name2 + ".txt", false), code);

        if (isValidIdentifier(original_text)) {
  writer.write("«" + original_text + "» - допустимое значение");  
} else
{
  writer.write("«" + original_text + "» - недопустимое значение");
}
System.out.println();  
//очистка буфера 
writer.flush();
}    

public static boolean isValidIdentifier(String original_text) {       
if (!original_text.matches("[$_\u0401-\u04F9\u0041-\uFB06]+[$_0-9\u0401-    \u04F9\u0041-\uFB06]+")) {
return false;
} 

String[] keyWords = {"boolean","volatile","else","instanceof","switch","true","goto","abstract","enum","int","static","false","break","assert","extends","interface","strictfp","null","continue","byte","final","long","super","do","case","finally","native","synchronized","double","catch","float","new","throw","protected","char","for","package","throws","this","class","if","private","transient","short","const","implements","public","try","while","default","import","return","void", "/", "","""};
      if (Arrays.asList(keyWords).contains(original_text))
{               
    return false;
}
return true;
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оказалось код верный, просто блокнот Windows сохранял не в UTF-8 как было написано, а в UTF-8 BOM. Это можно увидеть если открыть файл через Notepad.